# Generate passport token when user using social login in rest API

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

I am using passport auth for an laravel application. This is the back end/server side setup. Only rest APIs would be there. I am able to generate token when user enters password and email at sign in but what should I do when user choosing facebook to sign up, because this time only facebook id and other details.